# Failed to load Analytics native module. Android. React native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, apk, gradlew

I have problem with Android release build.On first launch my application crashes with `com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Error: Failed to load Analytics native module`. `FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules`.

After first crash it continue to work fine and on dev mode it works fine also.

I use `@segment/analytics-react-native`, but it also works well. On iOS release version everything works without any errors.

Any ideas what can be a problem?